# PHP dynamic associative array in 'for' loops

Tags: php, arrays

I have this case to assign values to associative arrays.

```
for($i=0;$i<$dynamicNumber;$i++){

    for($j=0;$j<$dynamicNumber2;$j++){
          $array[$i][$j]['key'] += $value;
    }

}
```

Because is an addition operator it will first look for the array key value and add with the $value.

Since the key is not defined previously it will throw and "undefined index" error in the first loop.

I am in a process of converting and old php project and this case is like thousand times.

My shortest way is doing it like:

```
for($j=0;$j<$dynamicNumber2;$j++){
          $array[$i][$j]['key'] = ($array[$i][$j]['key'] ?? 0) + $value;
    }
```

Can this be improved ?

Comment: You could write a small function - something like `addToKey(&$key, $value) { $key = ($key??0)+$value;}` then use as `addToKey($array[$i][$j]['key'], $value);`

Comment: This is a code review question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no error or problem in the code